# Radio buttons across forms

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I've got an HTML div composed of many rows (using angular so the number of rows is dynamic). Inside these rows are columns or <td> tags. Inside some of these <td>'s are forms with radio buttons. If a radio button in one form is clicked, I need  all the other radio buttons in the same column (but different rows and therefore, different forms) to become unchecked. Normally, if the radio buttons all belong to the same group, this functionality is built in. I'm trying to link radio buttons across form elements. Is this possible? How?

Comment: Is it an option to give all radio buttons of each column a common class so you can use the class to uncheck them dynamically?

Comment: That's an option. Is that good practice? Is there another way? Or perhaps a library that does this?

Comment: This is the simplest and hackless way I can think of doing it. Using a library for this just seems like overkill to me. I'll post my suggestion as an answer so we'll know that it's not the best way if many people downvote it, or that it's a good solution if the opposite happens :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each of your radio buttons that belong to the same row a common class so you can uncheck them dynamically. A similar option is to use HTML5's `data` attribute so you can use jQuery's `.data()` method ([see more here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)), which would work similar to adding a common class between them.

For example, every radio button in the first row would have `data-row="1"`, while buttons in the second row would have `data-row="2"`, and so on.